# L ={a^n.b^n | n>=0} , what is difference between L^2 and L.L?

Tags: formal-languages

[image]

which option is correct? please explain why other are wrong if any one is correct

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're not a homework-answering service.

Comment: I have confusion about option (a) and (b), because of L^2 and L.L.  is L^2 = L.L?

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: " is L^2 = L.L" -- apply the definition of $\_^2$.

Comment: option (a) and (c) are same..

Comment: @AlwynMathew (a) and (c) are not the same: "ab" is only in (c) but not in (a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$L^2=L\cdot L$ by definition and $L\cdot L=\{xy\mid x\in L\land y\in L\}$. Can you use that to get the answer?

Comment: (b) will be correct .

Comment: @PiyushRaghuwanshi. Close, but there's no reason that $x$ and $y$ must be the same string. In other words, among the answers you proposed, $n$ and $m$ don't have to be equal.